# Find the remainder without Fermat's Theorem.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

**Find the remainder when $27^{3333}$ is divided by 31.**

So far, I tried rewriting it as $3^{9999} \equiv x\pmod {31}$, and I noted that $gcd (3,31)=1$ but I don't seem to be getting anywhere.

All the similar examples I could find refer to Fermat's Theorem, which we have not covered in class yet, or binary representation, which our professor did not go over and says it is not necessary -- he's sticking to decimal representation.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Modulo $31$, we are looking at $(-4)^{3333}$, so $-2^{6666}$. Note that $2^5\equiv 1\pmod{31}$.

Comment: Thank you - that was exactly the hint I needed. I need to remember to break down as far as possible. I got to -4, but did not go further with it.

Comment: @Carolyn: You are welcome. Since we could not use Fermat's Theorem, we needed a "trick," or heavy-duty computation.